# Change order of divs by "flex order number" on filter select with jquery

Tags: javascript, css, algorithm, sorting, event-handling

Instead of changing the order of divs by jquery only, I just want to "**change the flex order number**" of every div, after selecting a sort method, with jquery.

For example, my select box:

```
<div id="sorting">
  <select>
    <option value=".best">Best</option>
    <option value=".worst">Worst</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

My list structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="score">12</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="score">7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="score">42</div>
  </div>
  <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

The css for the list:

```
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper > .item {
    order: 0;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

What I want:

On selecting `".best"`, the div with the highest score should get the lowest "**flex order number**" and so on (for each div). On selecting `".worst"`, the div with the lowest score should get the lowest "**flex order number**" aso.

My current "jquery only" way:

```
var best = $('#wrapper > .item').sort(function(b, a) {
    var a1 = $(a).find('.score').text(), b1 = $(b).find('.score').text();
    return a1.localeCompare(b1, false, {numeric: true})
});
```

The problem is, that I have to reinitialize all scripts for the `".item"` divs after changing the order. That's something I want to prevent by the changing just the "flex order number".

Comment: Why does the OP not simply remove the element nodes, while storing each into an array, sort the array accordingly and append each element node again, according to its newly sorted precedence? No fiddling around, neither with css nor with events.

Comment: @PeterSeliger  Indeed, removing elements from the DOM, doesn't remove Events.   There is also a nice performance boost if you do this, updating the DOM live by changing CSS can cause document reflow.  If the only reason the OP is using CSS order is because of this, it's possibly the wrong reason.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the this by changing the flex order of each `.item` element based on the selected sorting option using jQuery.

#### Try below Code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#sort-select").change(function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var items = $("#wrapper > .item").toArray();

    items.sort(function (a, b) {
      var aScore = parseInt($(a).find(".score").text());
      var bScore = parseInt($(b).find(".score").text());

      if (selectedValue === ".best") {
        return bScore - aScore; // Sort in descending order for best
      } else {
        return aScore - bScore; // Sort in ascending order for worst
      }
    });

    // Update the flex order based on the sorted order
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      $(items[i]).css("order", i);
    }
  });
  $("#sort-select").trigger("change");
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper > .item {
    order: 0;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sorting">
    <select id="sort-select">
        <option value=".best">Best</option>
        <option value=".worst">Worst</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="score">12</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="score">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="score">42</div>
    </div>
    <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for your support! That looks really close to what I was searching for! I will try it - back soon.

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to give it a try.

Comment: @Pepe ... _"It is working like a charm! Exactly what I was looking for - big thx!"_ ... should not be the only criteria for judging a solution. The underlying approach is poorly chosen. What you are/were looking for can be solved in a much simpler manner.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JQuery to implement this. Modern browsers can handle what you're using JQuery for (at least in this case anyway).

---

**Solution**

I wouldn't try to solve it in one step (it would make maintenance a PITA later).

1. First you collect the elements in a list by extracting the relevant value.
2. Then, you sort this list the way you want (based on the extracted value).
3. As a third step, you apply the flexbox order based on the result of your sorting.

This way your DOM structure won't change, just the style property of each element.

Don't specify a flexbox order out of the box. Let the script handle that.

*I used ES 6 syntax (I'm more used to it, and it's way easier to work with).*

```js
function sortItems() {
  // get the list DOM elements
  const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

  // collect them as a key-value pair (the DOM element is the key, 
  // the sorting criteria is the value)
  const data = [];
  items.forEach((element) => {
    data.push({
      element,
      value: parseInt(element.querySelector('.score').innerText),
    });
  });
  
  // get the value of the select element
  const sorter = document.querySelector('#sorting select');
  const value = sorter.value;

  // sort based on it
  switch (value) {
    default: 
    case ".best":
      data.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.value === b.value)
          return 0;
        return a.value < b.value ? 1 : -1;
      });
      break;
    case ".worst": 
      data.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a.value === b.value) 
          return 0;
        return a.value < b.value ? -1 : 1;
      });
      break;
  }

  // add the flexbox order based on the list order
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i].element.style.order = i;
  }
}

// change event
document.querySelector('#sorting select').addEventListener('change', sortItems);
// just to reflect the state of the selector
sortItems();
```

```css
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper > .item {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="sorting">
  <select>
    <option value=".best">Best</option>
    <option value=".worst">Worst</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="score">12</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="score">7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="score">42</div>
  </div>
  <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your interesting way and your explanation! For big data, your way might be the better solution. For me it feels a bit overkill at the moment for my little project. But maybe I'll try it later - thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could pair each score with the corresponding `.item` element and then sort by score. This gives you a sorted array of pairs. Then iterate that array and assign the sequence number to the `.item` element's `order` CSS attribute:

```js
$("#sorting > select").change(function () {
    if (!this.value) { // Blank selected? Restore original order
        return $("#wrapper .item").css({order: 0});
    }
    // Extract the scores together with their item element
    const keyItemsByValue = $('#wrapper .score').get().map((div) => [$(div).text(), $(div).parent()]);
    // Sort them numerically
    keyItemsByValue.sort(([a], [b]) => a - b);
    // Take the user's sort order into account
    if (this.value == '.best') keyItemsByValue.reverse();
    // Apply CSS to order items
    keyItemsByValue.forEach(([, $div], order) => $div.css({order}));
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
}

#wrapper > .item {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sorting">
  <select>
    <option></option>
    <option value=".best">Best</option>
    <option value=".worst">Worst</option>
  </select>
</div>


<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <span class="score">12</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="score">7</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <span class="score">42</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From both of my provided comments ...

> *Why does the OP not simply remove the element nodes, while storing each into an array, sort the array accordingly and append each element node again, according to its newly sorted precedence? No fiddling around, neither with css nor with events.*

> *@Pepe ... **"It is working like a charm! Exactly what I was looking for - big thx!"** ... should not be the only criteria for judging a solution. The underlying approach is poorly chosen. What you are/were looking for can be solved in a much simpler manner."*

Example code which implements the formerly mentioned approach.

```js
// wrapper child-node specific sort function helpers.
function worstPrecedence(a, b) {
  return Number(a.textContent.trim()) - Number(b.textContent.trim());
}
function bestPrecedence(a, b) {
  return Number(b.textContent.trim()) - Number(a.textContent.trim());
}

// main task ... (re)rendering of the item precedence.
function rerenderItemPrecedence(whichPrecedence) {
  const $wrapper = $('#wrapper');

  $wrapper

    .children('.item')
    .toArray()

    // - create array of wrapper child-nodes by
    //   removing each separately from the DOM.
    .reduce((itemList, elmNode) => {

      itemList.push(
        elmNode.parentNode.removeChild(elmNode)
      );
      return itemList;

    }, []).sort(
      // - sort wrapper child-nodes according
      //   to the chosen precedence/sort order.
      whichPrecedence
    )
    .forEach(elmNode =>
      // - append each wrapper child-node to
      //   its wrapper parent-node again.
      $wrapper.append(elmNode)
    );
}
function handleSortOrderChange({ currentTarget: { value } }) {
  rerenderItemPrecedence(
    value === '.best' && bestPrecedence || worstPrecedence
  );
}

// assure the correct initial sort order.
handleSortOrderChange({
  currentTarget: $('#sorting select')[0]
});

// register the sort order change handling.
$('#sorting select')
  .on('change', handleSortOrderChange);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
#wrapper > .item {
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="sorting">
  <select>
    <option value=".best">Best</option>
    <option value=".worst">Worst</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="score">12</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="score">7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="score">42</div>
  </div>
  <!-- and so on -->
</div>
```